# How to set Apple TV's language back to English?

Tags: appletv, settings, ui, language, internationalization

So, our daughter thought it would be funny to change the Apple TV's language setting. She is now complaining that she can't watch TV shows. Of course she can't, because nobody can figure out how to sign in to the account again, since the menus are all in... Nepali? I'm not sure.

[image]

Anyway, I think our OS is the most recent version, so can someone else with an Apple TV in English please post images showing how to navigate to the language setting, so that I can change the language back to English?

<sup>And isn't it about time Apple established a universal indicator for language settings so that no matter what language is set, one can navigate to the settings and change them? If one must understand the current language in order to change the language, isn't that a usability problem? Sure, most of us don't screw around with the language settings for fun, but then there are those of us who have kids...</sup>

### Edit:

The model, when looked up via serial number, is listed as: 
Apple TV HD

[image]

Comment: tvOS will appear somewhat differently depending on model of Apple TV, and different models have various ways of navigating them, so it'd be good if you can clarify what model you're asking about.

Comment: @Monomeeth I added the model name, to the extent that I was able to identify from the serial number. Since I can't navigate the menu, I am unable to supply more specific details about the OS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top item in the main settings menu is General > on the next page you want Language, which is item 1 (of 2) in the 4th group.

If you ignore the groups, it's item number 14 on mine.